# How to enforce default value if user bypass non-required fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have entity with email field like this, field is not required, I just do not want to have nulls in DB columns:

```
class Entity {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column()
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    protected $email = '';

}
```

How can I enforce default value if user bypass this field in a form?
Now validator throws an error that field cannot be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you care about is not having nulls in the DB then a couple options:

1. In the DB, assign a default value to the email column in the DB.
2. In PHP, create a "NA" or similar value when the email is empty.

But your logic of having a non-required field unable to be blank does not make sense. You can either make it required or allow a null value.